# How to split routes to different files with Redux and React-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have many routes in my application. Each has an onEnter method that loads data from an API and fires an action (thunk) on the store.

```
const routeConfig = [
    {path: '/tutorial/:tutorialId', component: Tutorial, onEnter: tutorialEnter},
    {path: '/session/:sessionId', component: App, onEnter: sessionEnter},
    {path: '/session/:userId/:sessionId', component: App, onEnter: userSessionEnter},
    {path: '/template/:language/:sessionId', component: App, onEnter: templateEditEnter},
    {path: '/snippet/:language/:appType/:sessionId', component: App, onEnter: snippetEditEnter},
    {path: '/prepare/:sessionId', component: Library, onEnter: galleryPrepareEnter},
    {path: '/launch/:comboId', component: Launch, onEnter: launchEnter},
    ... more

];

const renderStore = () => {
    rootElement = document.getElementById('root')

    render(
        <MuiThemeProvider>
            <div className="root">
                <Provider store={store}>
                    <Router history={history} routes={routeConfig} onUpdate={onPageView}/>
                </Provider>
            </div>
        </MuiThemeProvider>,

        rootElement
    );
}
```

example for an OnEnter method:

```
const launchEnter = (location) => {
    let {comboId} = location.params;

    store.dispatch(appActions.getComboDetails(comboId))
    store.dispatch(appActions.getBuildRequestsForCombo(comboId))
}
```

I want to split the routes and OnEnter scripts into different files. I can create a method that returns an array with some of the routes but how do I get access to the store? Two ideas which I had seemed flawed:

#### Idea #1 - wrapping the store. LaunchRoutes.js:

```
export const getRoutes = (store) => {

    const launchEnter = (location) => {
        let {comboId} = location.params;

        store.dispatch(appActions.getComboDetails(comboId))
        store.dispatch(appActions.getBuildRequestsForCombo(comboId))
    }

    return [
        {path: '/launch/:comboId', component: Launch, onEnter: launchEnter},
    ];
}
```

This doesn't feel right to have the store locked in this closure.

#### Idea #2 - accessing the store via a global

```
const store = window.store;

const launchEnter = (location) => {
    let {comboId} = location.params;

    store.dispatch(appActions.getComboDetails(comboId))
    store.dispatch(appActions.getBuildRequestsForCombo(comboId))
}

export const getRoutes = (store) => {

    return [
        {path: '/launch/:comboId', component: Launch, onEnter: launchEnter},
    ];
}
```

This even seems a worst idea than the first one using the **window** as a cheap way out of it.

Any ideas how to properly split the routes?

Comment: Are you avoiding `connect`ing the route components and doing data fetching in `component(Will|Did)Mount` for any particular reason? https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v3.0.0/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md#fetching-data

Comment: Yes, for simple components I go with the componentWillMount but as some components require complicated data fetching (caching and such), it makes more sense to me to put in the route (at a higher level). Moreover, the route's component acts as a container to other components, splitting the data fetching to many inner components will make things harder to follow and anyway, in this application, the page cannot function without the entire data tree.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution would be to go the same route as `react-router` does with [`browserHistory`](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/modules/browserHistory.js) and `hashHistory`, which would be to create a store module and export your store instance from there.

This may or may not work based on your code structure, but essentially you would have a `store.js`:

```
import { createStore } from 'redux'
import reducers from './reducers'

export default createStore(reducers)
```

You could then import the `store` throughout your project wherever you need to interact with it.

```
// index.js
import React from 'react'
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'

import store from './store'

render((
  <Provider store={store}>...</Provider>
), holder)
```

and

```
// launchEnter.js
import store from './store'

const launchEnter = (location) => {
  let {comboId} = location.params;
  store.dispatch(appActions.getComboDetails(comboId))
  store.dispatch(appActions.getBuildRequestsForCombo(comboId))
}
```